# SveleteKit / Vite.js how to link in large static content

Tags: node.js, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm using svelete to drive some tools I'm using internally.  I found it easy to get started with sveletekit, but I don't really want to do a deep dive into how it works, and the documentation is opaque.

I have a several (huge) directories of static content that I want to serve from within my app.  I found that it worked if I simply symlined my content directories into project/static/symlink and I could get at them, using 'npm run dev' to start the server.

But now I'm running into problems. There are so many files I'm hitting the system inotify limits, and I don't really want them watched by sveletekit anyway.

a) How do I serve basic static content without any vite of svelte bells and whistles?
b) 'npm run dev' starts up slow.  How do I build and run the site (WITHOUT copying all of the above static content) for regular running?  'npm build' is taking forever and I'm guessing it's paging through all that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your `vite.config.js` to exclude the static assets from being watched

```js
server: {
    watch: {
      ignored: ["/static/**"],
    },
  },
```

I don't see a way around the long build times because sveltekit has to copy all the assets into the build folder, you can ignore those files for build and have a script that does it for you (or symlinks it to the build folder) but that son't really work for cloud deployments

Comment: No, this doesn't work after all. Still getting ENOSPC errors as it tries to watch all the files.